# Where do I add in an re.search in this python code?

Tags: python, regex

I have some python code to change the severities of incoming SNMP traps on the NMS I am using.

The incoming SNMP traps contain objects that are ranges of numbers for a given severity level. The below code works if the the incoming object numbers are singular, 1,2,3,4,5 etc. But it doesnt work for the below when trying to match a regex number range.

```
## This gets the alarmTrapSeverity function and creates a variable called            Severity to hold the value
if getattr(evt, 'alarmTrapSeverity', None) is not None:
Severity = getattr(evt, 'alarmTrapSeverity')



 ## This part runs through the Severity to assign the correct value
 if str(Severity) == '0':
 evt.severity = 0
 elif str(Severity) == '([1-9]|1[0-9])':
 evt.severity = 1
```

Please could you advise the correct way to do this. My regex skills are still developing.

Comment: Why do you need a regex? `if 1 <= int(Severity) <= 19:`

Comment: This could work too. Ill try this also, thank you @tripleee

Comment: Yeah this actually works better than what I had in mind originally. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding this correctly, in the else-if statement you would like to perform a regular expression search in order to confirm a match. My approach would look like this,

```
## This gets the alarmTrapSeverity function and creates a variable called            
Severity to hold the value
if getattr(evt, 'alarmTrapSeverity', None) is not None:
Severity = getattr(evt, 'alarmTrapSeverity')


regex = re.compile(r'([1-9]|1[0-9])')

## This part runs through the Severity to assign the correct value
if str(Severity) == '0':
    evt.severity = 0
elif regex.search(str(Severity)) != None:
    evt.severity = 1
```

This would search the str(Severity) variable for a matching substring, which in this case would be the string containing numbers between 1-19. Then as long as it finds a match, sets evt.severity = 1.

Also, looking back at your question, if you were having issues with finding numbers between 1-19 with that regex, another example which works might be,

```
"10|1?[1-9]"
```

Comment: Thank you Matthew H, great name by the way. Ill give this a go now.

Comment: Figured I would mention in case it might be useful, the reason your regular expression might not work is because when there is a | (or) in  a regular expression, it considers each option in order. So if it finds one, it doesn't bother checking for the rest. Since you look for 1-9 before you look for 10-19, it will find 1-9 in 10-19 and not bother checking for 10-19.